# Mapbox Callout Accessory

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, mapbox, callout

I was wondering if Mapbox had any other callout buttons rather than just the seven provided?

```
let button = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
```

Or if there was a quick fix to converting these UIButtons into UIImages in order to create my own buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the methods `func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, leftCalloutAccessoryViewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> UIView?` and `func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, rightCalloutAccessoryViewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> UIView?` to create your own. Set the button type to `.custom`

For example:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, leftCalloutAccessoryViewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> UIView? {
    // We're not concerned with the user annotation.
    guard annotation is CameraAnnotation || annotation is NoteAnnotation else {
        return nil
    }
    // Callout height is fixed; width expands to fit its content.
    let deleteButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
    deleteButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
    deleteButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "delete"), for: .normal)
    deleteButton.tag = 100
    return deleteButton
}
```

Comment: No problem. Can I ask you to accept the answer? It's not an ego thing - it's just more rep unlocks more options for me to help the site.